# How to test database methods and get code coverage xUnit ASP.NET

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, xunit

I initially used the [Moq](https://documentation.help/Moq/) library for testing, since I don't actually want to mess the data in my database. However, I quickly realized instead of running the code in some way and faking the result, it just does the latter. I need to reach a code coverage of at least 80% due to a project deadline in a couple of days, and the database is a big chuck of the code.
I have some methods for my DB in separate classes such as:

`public Task<bool> DBEmpty();`

`public Task<bool> ParseToDB();`

`public Task<Customer> GetCustomer(int id);`

I want these methods something like mocked, so I don't mess my data, but also get code coverage. Unless it is customary that database methods are traditionally marked with  `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]`, is it? My only previous experience with unit testing is a calculator app, I am brand new to this sport and this is the first time I use a c# testing framework (xUnit).

Comment: In my ASP.NET project I create a separate DB instance for each UnitTest (the framework I use for testing does it automatically behind the scenes and I inject a pre-configured DB context into each test), I use [in memory SQlite](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) but you can use anything you want. This also guarantees that I get no collisions and leave no data behind that could pollute the DB. Alternatively you can track the entities you created during your unit test and delete them afterwards

Comment: I would use an in memory database to do simple checks on the repositories. Bear in mind that an in memory database won't check data validity or relationships

Comment: I read both comments from scottdavidwalker and MindSwipe.  I did come across the in memory database solution and will further investigate if this is feasible given the time constraints I got.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer in my case:** I did not end up using an in memory database, since there was not enough time for this in my case. I used Moq to fake all responses from the database/service classes and excluded them from coverage.